# manipulate string to substring on java

Tags: substring

after long googling days, no success.

i just want to get the first number from "result=0.23 562"
here is my code, i will appreciate any help! 
by the way this is an android app
the function `ServerTransfer()` just getting data from phone's USB.

```
package com.WiMiapplication.wimi;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class trackingActivity extends Activity{

    TextView Fields;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.trackingsub);

    }


        @Override
         protected void onResume() {
         super.onResume();

        new ServerTransfer(){
            int indexend=0;
            int indexstart=0;
            private String Dude ="3";
            @Override
            public void onPostExecute(String result){
            for(int i=0;i<=result.length();i++){
                        String Spectate=Character.toString(result.charAt(i));
                            if(!Spectate.equals(" ")){
                                 indexend++;
                            } else{

                                Dude =result.substring(result.indexOf(" ") + 3);
                            }


            }
        Fields = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.X_location);
        Fields.setText(result);
            }





        }.execute();



}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
Dude =result.split(" ")[0];
```

Comment: correction! it worked! "String r = result.split(" ")[0];" thank you Dude! :)